# getting duplicate primary key error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO REQUEST (OrderNumber, CustomerID, ItemID)
VALUES ('10011', '10', '1001'),
       ('10011', '10', '1007'),
       ('10011', '10', '1014'),
       ('10021', '05', '1008'),
       ('10021', '05', '1014'),
       ('10031', '07', '1014'),
       ('10031', '07', '1019'),
       ('10041', '31', '1015'),
       ('10041', '31', '1007'),
       ('10041', '31', '1024'),
       ('10051', '50', '1014'),
       ('10051', '50', '1004'),
       ('10051', '50', '1011'),
```

Comment: can you share the output of `desc request`

Comment: which fields make up the PK here ?

Comment: The PK is the OrderNumber which starts at 10011

Comment: you are inserting 10011 thrice and so with the other order numbers. Thats why the error. Doesnt that answer your question?

Comment: PrimaryKey needs to be unique. That's about it. Everything else looks OK.

Comment: ok lean on the old Delete link :p

Comment: If a customer orders multiple items on one order how do I show this? This is where I am stuck

Comment: ex (OrderNumber, CustomerID, ItemID, ItemID, ItemID)

Comment: Clearly you are not familiar with database design.  The table `REQUEST` definitely is not normalized.  Ideally, you will have an `Order` table that has `OrderNum`, and `CustomerId` at least.  Then you will have another table `OrderDetail` that has foreign key references the `Order` table.  The columns such as `OrderNum`, `ItemId`, `Quantity`.

Comment: I am not familiar and am just trying to finish a project.

Comment: ok but even if I follow that idea and normalize it, how would I add multiple items to one order? If a customer 01 orders 3 items on one order, how do you show that in a table?

Comment: @Eric: Clearly you are not familiar with the lingo: it's normalized but not fully normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a new table that holds the many to many relationship between REQUEST and ITEMS

For example for table REQUEST and ITEMS

```
CREATE TABLE REQUEST (
  OrderNumber   Integer,
  CustomerID    Integer,  
  OrderDate     DateTime,
  PRIMARY KEY (OrderNumber)
);

Insert INTO REQUEST values
   ( 10011, 10, now()),
   ( 10041, 31, now());

CREATE TABLE ITEMS (
   ItemID          Integer,
   ItemDescription Varchar(50),
   PRIMARY KEY (ItemID)
);

Insert into ITEMS values
          ( 1001,'Screw'),
          ( 1007,'Rod'),
          ( 1015,'Nail');
```

This will be the new table

```
CREATE TABLE REQUEST_ITEMS (
     OrderNumber   Integer,
     ItemID        Integer,
     OrderQuantity Integer,
     PRIMARY KEY (OrderNumber, ItemID)
);

Insert into REQUEST_ITEMS values 
         (10011, 1001, 3),
         (10011, 1007, 25);

Insert into REQUEST_ITEMS values 
         (10041, 1015, 10),
         (10041, 1007, 15);
```

I hope this helps
Regards,